# Collapse multiple rows into one with title

Tags: sql-server

This is the original data

```
id    title        hired_reason fired_reason hired_date     fired_date
xxxxx Asst Washer   abc           xyz        1992-01-01     2004-08-31 
xxxxx Asst Washer   def            sdhj      2004-09-01     2005-02-28 
xxxxx washer        ghi            hsgd      2005-03-01     2007-12-31 
xxxxx washer        jkl            hdhs      2008-01-01     2012-03-31 
xxxxx washer        mno            sgh       2012-04-01     2013-04-18 
xxxxx washer        pqr            tshsj     2013-05-21     2016-01-06
```

I like the output to be:

```
id    title        hired_reason fired_reason hired_date     fired_date
xxxxx Asst Washer   abc           sdhj      1992-01-01  2005-02-28 
xxxxx Washer        ghi           tshsj     2005-03-01  2016-01-06
```

I am achieving this by using---

```
select id, min(hired_date), max(fired_date),seq
from (select ......,...,....
,row_number() over(order by hired_date) as line1
,row_number() over(partition by title ,order by hired_date) as line2 
,line1-line2 as seq
from table) table
 group by seq,id
```

all the test cases runs good but it fails in one scenario
ORIGINAL DATA

```
id  title hired_reason  fired_reason    hired_date  fired_date 
yyyy Wp     abc          hsdah          2017-01-01  2017-04-25 
yyyy W WP   def          shd            2017-04-26  2017-08-04 
yyyy Wp      ghi         jkl            2017-08-05  2017-10-20 
yyyy Mn     jkl          def            2017-10-21  2017-11-03 
yyyy Wp     mno          dfs            2017-11-04  2019-12-31
```

The output I like to be the same as my original data but with my query logic the obtained data is as follows

```
id  title hired_reason  fired_reason    hired_date  fired_date line1 line2 seq
yyyy Wp     abc          hsdah          2017-01-01  2017-04-25  1     1     0
yyyy W WP   def          shd            2017-04-26  2017-08-04  2     1     1
yyyy Wp      ghi         jkl            2017-08-05  2017-10-20  3     2     1
yyyy Mn     jkl          def            2017-10-21  2017-11-03  4     1     3
yyyy Wp     mno          dfs            2017-11-04  2019-12-31  5     3     2
```

I am doing group by seq and performing min and max values from the grouped data I am getting my output  like

```
id  title hired_reason  fired_reason    hired_date  fired_date
yyyy Wp     abc          hsdah          2017-01-01  2017-04-25 
yyyy W WP   def          shd            2017-04-26  2017-10-20
yyyy Mn     jkl          def            2017-10-21  2017-11-03 
yyyy Wp     mno          dfs            2017-11-04  2019-12-31
```

fired_date gets changed in 2nd row and 3rd row gets deleted as per my query

Thanks In advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what is the question here?

Comment: i like to collapse multiple data rows with same title into one. If a particular worked on a certain title for more than 2 terms back on back continuously , I would like to  collapse those multiple rows into 1.

Comment: Just basically, there are two different approaches to this. Either you use a pivot, but I think that is not what you want. The other approach which you are already using is to use window functions and filter thereafter with WHERE Line1 = 1 or something similar. Your question here is not clear enough to understand what you are trying to achieve.